# How to use classes from rt.jar in an android application?

Tags: java, android, dalvik

I am building an android application that references an external library.
The problem is that library uses java.beans.PropertyDescriptor and this causes Dalvik exception at runtime.

How can I solve this problem ? I found on another forum that it was possible to manipulate bytecode to load classes that are not known from Dalvik.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I solve this problem ?

Get the source code to the external library and rewrite it to avoid `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor`.

For example, you could:

- Find a copy of the source to an implementation `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` from someplace like Apache Harmony
- Refactor `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` to `some.other.package.PropertyDescriptor`
- Add `some.other.package.PropertyDescriptor` to your project
- Modify the source code of the external library to use `some.other.package.PropertyDescriptor`

Bear in mind that there may be many other problems with this library, which apparently was not written with Android in mind.

> I found on another forum that it was possible to manipulate bytecode to load classes that are not known from Dalvik.

Since there is no `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` on Android devices, this will not help you.